# After using mod_proxy the web application is no more accessible from other computer

Tags: apache, tomcat, alfresco, mod-proxy

I used apache proxy support in tomcat to remove the port number from url. Here is what I did,

In `http.conf` file I added
`LoadModule proxy_module mod_proxy.so
ProxyPass         /alfresco  http://localhost:8080/alfresco
ProxyPassReverse  /alfresco  http://localhost:8080/alfresco`

In `server.xml` file of tomcat
`<Connector port="8080" ...
              proxyPort="80"/>` (I didn't give proxy name)

Now I am able to access the web application using `http:\\localhost/alfresco` in my machine. But when I try this from other machine in my lan using `http:\\machine1\alfresco` I am getting page cannot be displayed error. But if I try `http:\\machine1` I am getting **It works** page of apache. What went wrong?

Previously I am able to use the application from other  machine.

Comment: What do the httpd logs say? Any errors recorded for your remote access?

Comment: I dont know what happened I installed apache again and I am able to login. Kind of weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `proxy port="80"` in server.xml file and now its working